# Classic ASP checkbox form questions insert into mysql and retrieve count

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have a simple questions form which has multiple choice/checkbox questions.
FORM:
q)Which of these types of olive oil does your holdhold use?
Options: PURE, EXTRA VIRGIN, POMACE

Q) For which of the following cooking applications does your household use olive oil?
Options:
Pan or shallow frying 
Dressing salads 
Roasting 
Preparing soups or sauces 
Deep frying 
Wok cooking 
Baking 
Preparing rice

Q) Why does your household use olive oil?
Options:
Is healthier 
Gives better result 
Adds a nice flavor 
Better suits my dishes 
Smells good

and so on.

This is my Mysql table and insert statement
ANSWERS TABLE:
Fields 
ID 
Q1
Q2
Q3

Stored Data : 
1 : Pure, Extra virgin : Pan or shallow, Roasting,Baking : Is healthier, smells good
2 : Pure : Deep frying, Wok cooking, Baking : Smells good, better suits my dishes

As you can see I am currently storing data in comma separated values.

This is my ASP insert statement:
sSQL = "INSERT into answers (q1,q2,q3) values ('" & q1 & "', '" & q2 & "', '" & q3 & "')"

I would like to generate a count for each option per question so that I can see what responses have been given.
Eg: 
Q1) Pure: 15
Extra Virgin: 20
Pomace :4

Q)Pan or shallow frying : 15
Dressing salads :23
Roasting :10
Preparing soups or sauces :45
Deep frying :10
Wok cooking :67
Baking :4
Preparing rice:5

and so on.
How do I do this?

OR how do I normalize the db and store values properly so that it can be retrieved with count/group query?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use queries like

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) from ANSWERS where Q1 = 'pure'
```

Comment: Yeah, but for each option I'd require to have a separate select statement?